# Steaming Audio from remote server to iPhone

Tags: audio, stream, ios7

I'm working on an app to be able to steam audio.mp3 from a remote server. I am new to coding and am looking for some direction on the best way to do this and the code that is needed. I know its a basic and elementary question but a response would be appreciated! thanks.